# mounting an attached volume in amazon Linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, volume, mount

i want to mount an attached volume in an amazon instance (Linux)
[when used the mount command without "-o nouuid" an error shows up why what is the use "-o nouuid" and i want to know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb62o.png)

first i tried to mount the volume in /mnt/root-volume/ directory on amazon Linux using the following command

```
mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/root-volume/
```

but this error showed up

```
mount: /mnt/root-volume: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

and then i searched on youtube and found to use " -o nouuid " in between the mount command and the directory path like the following but didn't mention why

```
[root@ip-172-31-39-229 mnt]# mount -o nouuid /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/root-volume/
[root@ip-172-31-39-229 mnt]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0   8G  0 part /mnt/root-volume
```

i want to know what is the purpose of "-o nouuid " command

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.